# If $T$ is self-adjoint, is the set of power series in $T$ closed?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $T$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, is the set of convergent power series in $T$ closed in the norm topology?

I ask because I'm reading some spectral theorems and I was wondering what the space $\overline{ \mathbb{C}[T] }$ is like.  It would be nice if it were just the set of convergent power series in $T$.

Edit: Actually this seems sort of unlikely since then every complex valued continuous functions on the spectrum of $T$ would be given by a power series, but I still haven't seen enough examples of spectra to rule this out. Even a self adjoint $T$ whose spectrum has a limit point would suffice to rule it out.

Comment: What happens if $T$ is multiplication by $x$ on $L^2[-1,1]$?  If $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and nowhere differentiable, then $f(T)$ is in $\overline{\mathbb C[T]}$, but I expect not equal to $g(T)$ for any power series $g$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer  Ahh, right.  The spectrum of T is precisely $[-1, 1]$, right?  In that case, it's definitely a counterexample.

Comment: I think that gives a satisfactory answer if you'd like to copy and paste it into an answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Tim, My reason for commenting instead of answering is not having rigorous justification come quickly to mind, and not having time to think about it at the moment.  No need to wait for me; if that comment really is enough, you (or anyone else) may post it as your own answer.

Comment: I struggled about more or less the same problem some time ago. The point is that the power series are really a proper(!) subset of the uniform closure of polynomials. To see this note that the uniform closure of polynomials over a compact interval gives *every* continuous function whereas the convergent power series are *only* the analytic functions. The rest is just adjusting this to the injective(!) continuous functional calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonas Meyer's comment gives an example of a self-adjoint $T$ whose spectrum is $[-1,1]$.  Then we may take the absolute value function, for instance, or even any continuous function whose zeros accumulate in $(-1,1)$ to see that that the space of continuous functions on the spectrum contains functions which are not power series. Since $C(\sigma (T))$ is isomorphic as a $C^\ast$-algebra to $\overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}$, we see that we have $$\mathbb{C}[T] \subset \{ \text{power series in T} \} \subsetneq \overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}$$ so that the set of power series in $T$ is not closed.